# Jumping from one square in a grid to another

Tags: java, math, vector, libgdx, game-physics

I'm programming a game where you have to jump from one driftwood to another. You can see what I have here:

[image]

Planks spawn at the top and scroll down. You can jump one tile up and one or two tiles left or right.

All elements (the planks and the player if he isn't jumping and standing on a plank) move every time  `draw(float delta)` is called:

```
setY(getY() + FlotsamGroup.yVelocity * delta);
```

This works fine, but if the player starts to jump I want him to land on the exact same coordinates the plank in this location has. With my code, he doesn't and with the time it looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the green lines around the player aren't at the same height from the surrounding planks, but the sides are correct, so it seems like x-axis works fine.

I think I somehow have to use a modified version of the speed-code from above, but I also want to make the player jump faster as the planks scroll down, and someday I want to include, that the whole game gets faster with the amount of planks you already successfully jumped (decrease the `FlotsamGroup.yVelocity-Value`)

```
protected class JumpAction extends Action {

    // Direction the player wants to jump to
    Direction direction;
    // The player actor
    Player player;
    // scalarVector is the vector, which has to be added to players position
    Vector2 scalarVector;
    // targetPosition is the players position add with the scalarVector
    Vector2 targetPosition;

    public JumpAction(Direction direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
        Gdx.app.log("", "Go to " + direction);

        /* Everytime we need to jump one tile up, so Y from scalarVector is everytime 1
           How much we have to go on x-axis dependens on the direction */
        scalarVector = new Vector2(0, 1);
        switch(direction) {
        case TWOLEFT:
            scalarVector.x = -2;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            scalarVector.x = -1;
            break;
        case UP:
            break;
        case RIGTH:
            scalarVector.x = 1;
            break;
        case TWORIGTH:
            scalarVector.x = 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean act(float delta) {
        if(player == null) {
            player = (Player) getActor();
            player.isJumping = true;
            targetPosition = new Vector2(player.getX() + GameGrid.getSquareSize() * scalarVector.x, player.getY() + GameGrid.getSquareSize() * scalarVector.y);
            Gdx.app.log("", "Target Vector " + scalarVector.toString() + " | Target Position " + targetPosition.toString());
        }

        // Somehow modify players position to smoothly move him to his target           
        player.setX(player.getX() + ( scalarVector.x / -(FlotsamGroup.yVelocity * delta)) );
        player.setY(player.getY() + ( scalarVector.y / -(FlotsamGroup.yVelocity * delta)) );

        // Check if player has been moved enough to stand on the new plank
        switch(direction) {
        case TWOLEFT:
        case LEFT:
            if(player.getX() < targetPosition.x)
                player.isJumping = false;
            break;
        case UP:
            if(player.getY() > targetPosition.y)
                player.isJumping = false;
            break;
        case RIGTH:
        case TWORIGTH:
            if(player.getX() > targetPosition.x)
                player.isJumping = false;
            break;
        }

        if(!player.isJumping) {
            // Player isn't jumping anymore, now we can set his position to target position
            player.setX(MathUtils.roundPositive(targetPosition.x));
            player.setY(MathUtils.roundPositive(targetPosition.y));
            // Return true to remove this action from the player-actor
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? your code is undocumented and I do not see any tile map or list of wood tiles ... also what is scalarVector oxymoron for? your movement should be smooth or with grid step ? where is player position?

Comment: I ask how I can let the player smoothly move into the exact middle of the tile where `direction` says he wants to jump to, so it doesn't look like in the second picture. I also have documented my code now. You can get the player-position with `player.getX();` or `player.getY();`, but I think you don't need a list of all wood tiles, since you know the velocity of all (`FlotsamGroup.yVelocity`) @Spektre

Comment: You may need to do something like `player.setY(MathUtils.roundPositive(targetPosition.y - targetPosition.width))`

Comment: `targetPosition.width`, I meant width of your `plank`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this:

```
   // Somehow modify players position to smoothly move him to his target           
    player.setX(player.getX() + ( scalarVector.x / -(FlotsamGroup.yVelocity * delta)) );
    player.setY(player.getY() + ( scalarVector.y / -(FlotsamGroup.yVelocity * delta)) );
```

To this (C++):

```
   // needed change in position
   float dx=targetPosition.getX()-player.getX();
   float dy=targetPosition.getY()-player.getY();
   // make it unit vector
   float q=sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
   float JumpSpeed=???; // here add some constant or variable jump speed you can use value of q for accelleration/breaking decision...
   if (q<1e-3) q=0.0; //here handle player reached target...  
   else q=1.0/q;
   dx*=q; dy*=q;
   // update position
   player.setX(player.getX()+(dx*JumpSpeed*delta));
   player.setY(player.getY()+(dy*JumpSpeed*delta));
   // here add the flow speed position update...
```

- targetPosition should hold the actual target position (so also modified with flow speed...)
- it is just modified linear interpolation between player and target position ...